# Scoreboard .txt scoreboard making for a tetris game

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, io

I am making a Tetris game in c# console. I have done most of the game but I am stuck with file handling. I haven"t really found anything related to this so I thought I might give it a shot and ask it.
So what I am trying to do is to save the Name of the player and the score to a txt file as NAME:SCORE then somehow sort it by the scores then print the top ten as a scoreboard.
Here is as how far I got:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace scoreb
{
    class Program
{
     private static Random _random = new Random();
        private static ConsoleColor GetRandomConsoleColor()
        {
            var consoleColors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor));
             return (ConsoleColor)consoleColors.GetValue(_random.Next(consoleColors.Length));
        }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 10;
        string[] names;
        string[] name = new string[n];
        string[] score = new string[n];
        int i = 0;
        while(name[i] != "*"){
            Console.WriteLine("Supply your name please!!");
            name[i] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Give your score!");
            score[i] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(name[i] + score[i]);
            names = new string[] { name[i] + "            " + score[i] };
            i++;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        //Printout
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ForegroundColor = GetRandomConsoleColor();
        Console.WriteLine("                   *****************************");
        Console.ForegroundColor = GetRandomConsoleColor();
        Console.WriteLine("                              HIGH SCORES");
        Console.ForegroundColor = GetRandomConsoleColor();
        Console.WriteLine("                   *****************************");
        Console.WriteLine();
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\asd.txt");
        Array.Sort(lines);
        string read = null;
        StreamReader b = File.OpenText("C:/asd.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("                   Név              Pont");
        while ((read = b.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            int j = 0;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = GetRandomConsoleColor();
            Console.WriteLine("                   " + (j + 1) + ". " + lines[j]);
            Console.WriteLine();
            j++;
        }
        b.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use linq to achieve what you want by using the code below

```
var scores = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\asd.txt")
         .Select(x => x.Split(":".ToCharArray())) // split name and score
         .Select(x => new
         {
             Name = x[0],
             Score = int.Parse(x[1])
         }) // create an object contains name and score for each line
         .OrderByDescending(x => x.Score) // sort result by score
         .Take(10); //get top 10
```

and then print your result in a `foreach` loop

```
foreach (var score in scores)
{
    Console.WriteLine(score.Score + "  " + score.Name);
}
```

but it has some limitations. if user name contains `:` then this will fail because the splitting part will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing and then reading/parsing a .txt file a simpler option would be to create a class that holds your player names and scores and then serializing it to XML and then saving it to a file. See here: [How to write object data to XML file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172873.aspx)

To read and deserialize the XML file to an object, [see this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172872.aspx) (related to above).

Also, to manage your names and scores don't do this:

```
    string[] name = new string[n];
    string[] score = new string[n];
```

Do something like this:

```
public class NameAndScore
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}

private List<NameAndScore> _namesAndScores = new List<NameAndScore>();
```

The List<> would be the object you would serialize and deserialize to the XML file.

Comment: Okay,thanks I haven't taught about XML i will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: @HambalkóBence: It's pretty easy and certainly much easier than creating and parsing your own format. Also please see my edit about how to better manage your names and scores.